# Chromecast Debug Mode Not Working

Tags: chromecast

So I read the API guidelines around registering the Chromecast, so I paid Google and did that.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterDevice

After 15 or so minutes, my serial was approved and now it has the status of "Ready For Testing".

So I plugged my device back in, tried restarting it and looking for the "enable update" option (doesn't exist on latest version).

I've tried this on several devices, and I've ensured the "Send Chromecast usage data and crash reports to Google" option is also selected - tested on both iphone and android phones, I've also tried restarting and restoring the devices to no avail.

I don't seem to be able to register my device and I definitely can't access my device on the http://ip:9222 - I've checked this on my router also, so its definitely correctly.

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What device are you using?  Can you see activity on the device when you attempt to connect to it?

Comment: I'm using a regular chromecast and I've tried setting up the software from both the iphone and android chromecast apps (Samsung S2, iphone 5s) - I attempted to access to the debug webpage from my desktop pc and macbook on the same networks.

Answer (score 0):

There might be different reasons for your issue. First lets make sure you are trying it correctly: is your own app running on chromecast when you try to connect the debugger? If not, that is a requirement. If your issue persists, then please contact our [support](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) to get additional help. I am not clear if you can run your own app (with your appid) and just not able to debug, or you cannot run your app either.

Comment: I've not written an app yet or anything? I was under the impression that I had to first register the device and then check the debug mode on port 9222? My understanding is that it returns a web api reference or such?

Comment: That is not the case, take a look at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging to see what it does and when you can expect that to be accessible.